# EXC BAD ACCESS after viewDidLoad in second viewController

Tags: iphone

The HDLogOnViewController passes two variables to the HDDomicileViewController in the 
tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of HDLogOnViewController.

The app crashes with a EXC BAD ACCESS error after the viewDidLoad method of the HDDomicileViewController. The variables are verified correct in HDDomicileViewController.

I have enabled Zombies with no help. When I enable Guard Malloc the app runs normally. In the output view of XCode there is no indication of what is causing the error. I have researched many EXC BAD ACCESS threads here and have tried using properties instead of instance variables. I have used four if statements instead of if else if. When doing this the app would run normally with only one if statement but would crash with more than one. Also, with the four if statements I could comment out the statements of each and it would crash, making it appear the problem was in the if condition.

How can I discover what is causing the error?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellLabel = [NSString stringWithString:[[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] cellTitleLabels] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

if ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Domicile"]) {

    tableViewArray = [[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] domiciles];
    tableViewArrayName = @"domiciles";

    NSLog(@"indexPath row is %i", [indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"array name is %@", [[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] cellTitleLabels] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
}

else if  ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Position"]) {

    tableViewArray = [[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] positions];
    tableViewArrayName = @"positions";

    NSLog(@"indexPath row is %i", [indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"array name is %@", [[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] cellTitleLabels] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
}

 else if ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"BidRound"]) {

    tableViewArray = [[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] bidRounds];
    tableViewArrayName = @"bidRounds";

    NSLog(@"indexPath row is %i", [indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"array name is %@", [[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] cellTitleLabels] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
}

else if ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Month"]) {

    tableViewArray = [[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] months];
    tableViewArrayName = @"months";

    NSLog(@"indexPath row is %i", [indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"array name is %@", [[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore] cellTitleLabels] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
}

HDDomicileViewController *domicileViewController = [[HDDomicileViewController alloc]init];
[domicileViewController setSelectedArray:tableViewArray];
[domicileViewController setSelectedArrayName:tableViewArrayName];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:domicileViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Where are your viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear methods?

Comment: can you tell exactly where it is crashing, do step by step debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I began getting inconsistent behavior so I went back to reading more posts here.

I solved the problem by following a suggestion to correct all errors found after analyzing the project. I corrected a few seemingly unrelated errors such as "value stored to 'pairing' during it's initialization is never read". I am not sure if this directly solved the problem but somewhere in the process the problem went away.

FYI

The app was crashing after the viewDidLoad method and before the viewWillAppear method. Step by step debugging led me to machine code which I know nothing about.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"selectedArray count is %i",[selectedArray count]);
   NSLog(@"selectedArray name is %@",selectedArrayName);
   NSLog(@"checkedRowMonth is %i",[[HDLogOnStore sharedStore]checkedRowMonth]);

}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```